# Proving Convexity - or Not - for a Set

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $\Omega = \left \{X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\;|\;X^TAX+B^TX+X^TB+C \succ 0\right \}$ where $A \in \mathbb{S}^m, B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, $ and $C \in \mathbb{S}^n$

I want to decide whether $\Omega$ is convex or not.

What I have so far: Take $X, Y \in \Omega$, and let $t \in [0,1]$. Then, it follows that
\begin{align*}
&(tX+(1-t)Y)^TA(tX+(1-t)Y)+B^T(tX+(1-t)Y)+(tX+(1-t)Y)^TB+C = \\
&t^2X^TAX+t(1-t)X^TAY+t(1-t)Y^TAX+(1-t)^2Y^TAY+tB^TX+(1-t)B^TY+tX^TB+(1-t)Y^TB+C =\\
& t^2X^TAX+t(B^TX+X^TB) + (1-t)^2Y^TAY+(1-t)(B^TY+Y^TB) + C + \color{blue}{t(1-t)X^TAY+t(1-t)Y^TAX}
\end{align*}
If we did not have the term in blue color, then it would follow that $tX+(1-t)Y \in \Omega$ so that this set is convex. However, I don't know how to deal with this term. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. Take the case $m=n=1$, $A=1$, $B=0$, $C=-1$. Then $$\Omega=\{x: x^2-1 \ge 0\} = (-\infty,-1] \cup [1,+\infty)$$